# OCR for form processing

Tags: ocr, forms

Could someone suggest me commercial or open-source software for form processing,
I work in school and we would use the software for our yearly enrollment test.
The students would fill the paper that looks similar to this [image: this]

Comment: In the US, this sort of sheet is often called a 'ScanTron sheet', from the name of the company that 'popularized' them.

Comment: Are you looking for an end-user solution or to develop your own application? For the latter, the [LEADTOOLS SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/) has an [OMR Processing Toolkit](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/ocr/omr) you can leverage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Software you are looking for is OMR (optical mark recognition)

[Vericare](https://www.omrhome.com/omr-software.php#:%7E:text=Use%20any%20normal%20scanner%20like%20Flatbed%2FADF%20scanner,or%20multi-function%20device%20to%20scan%20OMR%20bubble%20sheet.) and [Addmen](http://omrsheetscanner.com/video-answer-sheet-checker-operation.htm) say they can read bubble sheets with just a normal scanner.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know it was called OMR!